# CloudImport in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I'm trying to make an image viewer using `Manipulate` in the cloud to allow collaborators to see and compare different datasets.

I've tried several variants of the code which work fine for me when logged into the Wolfram cloud, but don't work when I open in another browser.

For this example I am only using two images, but the actual program will access hundreds of images so I need to be able to load files as needed.  Ideally the program would require a password to access, but public access would be a step in the right direction.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
CloudDeploy[ 
  Manipulate[ 
    If[ 
      i==1, 
      Show[CloudImport["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/nashua56/testimage/Heliosynchronous_orbit.png"],
        ImageSize->512
      ], Show[CloudImport["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/nashua56/testimage/elipticalorbit.png"] ,ImageSize->512]
 ], {i,1,2,1}], Permissions->"Public"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since those images are imported on the fly whoever accesses your cloud interface needs to have access to them too.

It was of course working for you while being logged in but from the incognito tab you can only see the main cloud object.

Run `CloudPublish` for your images' objects. Or `SetPermissions`.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give that a try!